# Name clashes in Go imports

Tags: import, go

Consider the Go code below..

```
package main

import "go/token"
import "python/token"

func main() {
     x := token.INDENT
}
```

What is the best way to solve the ambiguity of token in the above code? Is there something similar to the python expression of `import python.token as pytoken`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "go/token"
import pytoken "python/token"

func main() {
     g := token.INDENT    // "go/token"
     p := pytoken.INDENT  // "python/token"
}
```

[Import declarations](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Import_declarations)